# Is there a clever way to access a variable inside a wrapped function?

Tags: javascript

```
var x=(function(){var u=1;})();

console.log(x.u); // undefined
```

Is there any way at all to ether get, access or eventually console.log u?

Is there any code I could put inside x that might make u vulnerable / accessable from the outside?

Edit: I mean without returning u "directly". Is there any way of accidentally exposing u?

Comment: I don't think there is, but what is the need of that.

Comment: who minuses someone on there first question?? (I never said "I use" or "for"!)

Comment: well if you haven't noticed, `x` is undefined.  if you want to access the value outside make it global

Comment: @8Dk I recommend that you read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) and take the OOP part of this [track on Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript). It can be easily seen from your code that it is full of errors. Maybe, you might be trying to emulate OOP in JS.

Comment: [`var x = (function(){return {u: 1}})();`](http://jsfiddle.net/eLX57/)

Comment: Or: [`var x = (function(){var v = 1; return {u: v}})();`](http://jsfiddle.net/eLX57/1/)

Comment: @8DK Your question makes sense only if you meant `var x = function() { var u = 1;};` If you immediately evaluate the anonymous function (as you did above), the result x will simpy have the value `undefined`, and the variable `u` is lost by the evaluation.

Comment: The variable `u` would have already gone out of scope by the time `x` is assigned the function result. It would be a different question if you had just a function reference (in which case you could use `.toString()` hack)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** No. Private is private is private.

**Slightly longer answer:** Javascript does not protect from poorly conceived or executed coding, accidentally missing the `var` or returning or setting a property accessor in an object (`this.u = 1;`) (or accessing a variable in a subscope*), or weak coffee.

When used correctly with good understanding, exposing local/private variables within a scope must be done with some kind of intention. If there is some magic voodoo that can expose your precious variable, I have not seen it. (*Does the absence of evidence prove or disprove whether the yeti stalks this earth?!?*)

This includes, but is not limited to:

- Marauding aliens
- Twerking Miley Cyrus
- The Pope (be careful of the confessional, loose lips...)
- Fat Albert
- The Tea Party
- Austin Power's cat
- Nihilists
- Moops
- Baby rhinos
- El Yeti, née, Hefe

Et cetera, et cetera.

<sub>* Gunmen on the grassy noll?</sub>

Comment: Flying spaghetti monster

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way. After the function has been executed, there is no variable left, that has a reference to the value of `u`. Thus, the value of `u` will get garbage collected and will be lost.

Comment: It will be garbage collected, but when that occurs will be unknown.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes it is unknown, but the fact that it WILL happen is evidence that you cannot access the value of `u` anymore because anything that you would do to access it would result in undefined behaviour, since the value might or not be already garbage collected.

Comment: @JaredFarrish What's your point? As long as you keep a reference to the value it won't get garbage collected => no undefined behavior. If there is no reference left, the value is free to be collected at any time, so it might be still there or not => undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I hate the term "private" because it infers that the contents are protected from view.

```
<script id="MyScript">
x=(function(){var u=1;})();
</script>
<script>
myvar = document.getElementById("MyScript").innerText;
document.write(myvar);
</script>
```

u is destroyed, (as in does not leak memory), but the source code is not and is view-able, although parsing javascript with javascript is painful.

Comment: var u=Math.random(); print that!

Comment: @8DK that would be beyond my abilities.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
  var bar = {};
  bar.u = Number(0);
  var x = (function(foo){
    var u = foo.u = (function(n) { return !foo.n ? n : foo.n }(1)) ;
  })(bar);

console.log(bar.u, x, typeof x);
}());

console.log(x, u, window.bar, window.foo);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9qqpA/

Comment: The only reason that works is because [you're passing global scope (`window`)](http://jsfiddle.net/6jzfr/). This would qualify as either intentional (if done on purpose) or stumble-with-face-plant mistake.

Comment: Updated to local object `bar`. Thanks

Comment: That's not a local object, it's a global variable, e.g. `window.bar` (or it's in a higher scope). And it's the same situation, you're passing the variable and thus intentionally accessing the value that you are setting twice, one of which is *non-local*. This is more obfuscation that demonstration.

Comment: Not certain exactly what is meant by comment ? Please illuminate . Thanks

Comment: The question involves whether there's some way to programmatically access a private/local variable outside of it's scope. You've only proved that by passing a variable (albeit *cleverly obfuscating you've done so*) you can appear to set a private variable, but in fact you are only showing that you can set a property on that variable you've passed as an argument (again, *cleverly obfuscated*). This is a variation of the two examples I left under the question in the comments. So, what do you *think* you're demonstrating? I believe this is where the disconnect may lie.

Comment: And the `self`/`window` example *was* more clever. It took a good minute or two to figure out what you were doing there. `;)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can expose it by attaching it to the function itself:

```
var fn = function(){
    this.u = "Secret value!";
    return "Public value";
}
var x = fn.bind(fn)();

$('#returned').text(x);
$('#result').text(fn.u);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b29Xg/1/

I could see this being useful for debugging, but it also has the potential to introduce very stubborn bugs if you're not careful.